# Wifi keeps shutting down and asking for password, power management turns back on

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, broadcom

I am using the Asus PCE-AC68 wireless card which uses the Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03) chipset. The bcmwl-kernel-source driver is installed and connecting typically works for a few minutes after logging in before the connection drops and the network-manager keeps asking me for the password over and over. Sometimes it works for a few seconds/minutes and then drops again.

I've tried turning the power management off with "sudo iwconfig power off", but as soon as I try to connect to a network, it turns back on again.

Distro: Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1

I've tried:

- Setting ipv6 to `ignore`
- Adding `auto wlp6s0` 
  `iface wlp6s0 inet dhcp` 
  `wireless-power off`
  to `/etc/network/interfaces`
- `sudo iwconfig wlp6s0 power off`

`iwconfig` gives the following output:

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig` entry for wlp6s0:

```
wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:87:2c:b6:cf:93  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:139 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:612
          TX packets:227 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19824 (19.8 KB)  TX bytes:34566 (34.5 KB)
          Interrupt:19
```

Any ideas as to what I could try next?

Cheers!

Comment: I have installed WICD and there seems to be improvement... Perhaps network-manager couldn't handle the repeater signals with the same SSIDs with this card (works on my laptop though)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of uninterrupted network connectivity it seems like WICD works well as a workaround and that the problem lies with network-manager.